# How to force tracert command to pass by a specific ip?

Tags: networking, cmd, ip, jtracert

I need to test the delay in the connection from node A to node B .. But Since I don't have access to node A .. I will have to tracert node B using node C. So I need to force the trace route command to pass by A before reaching B .. How can this be done?
Any other command other than tracert will be accepted if same purpose can be fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flag -j as following:

**tracert -j node_A node_B node_C**

C:\Users\User>tracert /?

Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout]
               [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:

```
-d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
-h maximum_hops    Maximum number of hops to search for target.
**-j host-list       Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).**
-w timeout         Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
-R                 Trace round-trip path (IPv6-only).
-S srcaddr         Source address to use (IPv6-only).
-4                 Force using IPv4.
-6                 Force using IPv6.
```